# Comparison between two character arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, character

I have two character arrays of length 30 comparing the test key for a true/false questionnaire to the answers from individual candidates.

My issue is that when I try to compare the two characters arrays using an if function, it doesnt seem to record the comparison. I tried using a cout signal to check whether the comparisons functioned but still no progress.

I'm posting the for loop I used for comparisons!

```
for (int l=0; l>30; l++)
    {
        if (test_ans[l] == test_key [l])
        {
            s_correct++;
            cout << "c";
        }
        if (test_ans[l] == ' ')
        {
            s_blank++;
            cout << "b";
        }
        if ((test_ans[l] != test_key [l])&&(test_ans[l] != ' '))
        {
            s_bad++;
            cout << "w";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int l=0; l>30; l++)
              ^^^^
```

Do you see it now? ;)

Comment: Oops. I feel like an idiot now. It still isn't comparing the values properly between the arrays though. As in it's not identifying the ones that match correctly.

Comment: You need to show more than that. For example how are `test_ans` and `test_key` initialized. I'd recommend creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that. Also a hint: learn about `else if` and `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int l=0; l>30; l++)
//            ^^^^ <- Therein lies the secret of your problem.
```

to

```
for (int l=0; l < 30; l++)
```

because the statement `l < 30` is obviously `false` when `l` has just been initialized to `0`, and hence your loop wouldn't execute *even once*.

---

<sup>It was probably a typo, but here at StackOverflow, we recommend you to debug your code for the broad errors yourself, and then ask a question if the error still hasn't been fixed.</sup>